# Azure WebApi - No access from internet

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-envrmnt

my question is, how can I restrict access to my Azure WebApp/WebApi from internet.
For example the following architecture:

- One WebApi (Backend)
- One WebApp (Frontend)

The user should invoke the url of the WebApp (Frontend) but it should not be possible to invoke the url of the WebApi from the internet.

Ok I know I can restrict access in the WebApis through IP-Restrictions in the web.config. But is there no other solution?

I thought of something like this:

[Azure WebApi and Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPTHJ.jpg)
Is this possible and what resources I exactly need?

Comment: Take a look at this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-application-to-web-api - there's also a sample somewhere in there. If you don't care about authenticating the user you can use client_id and client_secret to acquire an access token from Azure AD and call your API. That's called client credential flow (weirdly enough).

Comment: Thank you. Yes Authentication via AzureAD is right but I want also to restrict the access to the Api over the internet.In other words: the Api should not have an external IP/DNS.

Comment: While you could use IP Restrictions and whitelist the outbound IP address of your App Service Plan hosting your Web App, i don't really see the point of going to all that trouble (which also makes for a brittle setup - think you redeploy to a different App Service Plan, now your whitelist is all wrong).

Comment: Yes and thats the reason why I want do restrict access not from IP addresses. I want to restrict something like "deny all request coming from internet"

Answer (score 0):

> the Api should not have an external IP/DNS, deny all request coming from internet

According to your description, you would not access the web api which is backend through url and do not want to use authentication filters in web api.

Actually, you could configure your router configuration to achieve it.
You could use the following code in **Global.asax**:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by creating an [internally load balanced App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-environment-with-internal-load-balancer). This is a pricey option, but it allows you to create an App Service App entirely within your VNET, and configure your load balancer to deny all public requests to the backend API.

If you're just looking to secure access to the backend API, I would suggest using Service Principle Auth.

[Enabling Auth on an App Service App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview)

[Configuring service principle auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal)